# How to access nested dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, json-normalize

I have a list of dictionaries (sorry It's a bit complex but I'm trying to display the real data) :

```py
[{'alerts': [{'city': ' city name1',
              'country': 'ZZ',
              'location': {'x': 1, 'y': 3},
              'milis': 1582337463000},
             {'city': ' city name2',
              'country': 'ZZ',
              'location': {'x': 1, 'y': 3},
              'pubMillis': 1582337573000,
              'type': 'TYPE2'}],
  'end': '11:02:00:000',
  'start': '11:01:00:000'},
 {'alerts': [{'city': ' city name3',
              'country': 'ZZ',
              'location': {'x': 1, 'y': 3},
              'milis': 1582337463000}],
  'end': '11:02:00:000',
  'start': '11:01:00:000'}]
```

In general the list structure is like this :

```
[
{ [
    { {},
    },
    { {},
    }
  ],
},
{ [
    { {},
    },
    { {},
    }
  ],
}
]
```

If I want to access `city name1`, I can access using this line of code : `alerts[0]['alerts'][0]['city']`.

If I want to access `city name2`, I can access using this code : `alerts[0]['alerts'][1]['city']`.

How can I access this in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use pandas

- `data` equals your sample list of dicts

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe and explode the list of dicts
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('alerts').reset_index(drop=True)

# json_normalize the dicts and join back to df
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.alerts))

# drop the alerts column as it's no longer needed
df.drop(columns=['alerts'], inplace=True)

# output
          start           end country         city         milis  location.x  location.y   type     pubMillis
0  11:01:00:000  11:02:00:000      ZZ   city name1  1.582337e+12           1           3    NaN           NaN
1  11:01:00:000  11:02:00:000      ZZ   city name2           NaN           1           3  TYPE2  1.582338e+12
2  11:01:00:000  11:02:00:000      ZZ   city name3  1.582337e+12           1           3    NaN           NaN
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! My plan was to put them in dataframe. Great that this cater for dictionary that is not available in other dictionary.

Comment: Accessing nested dictionaries can be an issue.  Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested loops:

- Where `alerts` equals the list of dicts

```
for x in alerts:
    for alert in x['alerts']:
        print(alert['city'])
```

Comment: Ok, I think this doesnt do what I want.

Comment: It accesses all the cities in a loop. Isn't that what you said?

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal? To get all city names?

```
>>> for top_level_alert in alerts:
        for nested_alert in top_level_alert['alerts']:
            print(nested_alert['city'])
city name1
city name2
city name3
```

Comment: It doesnt work when I applied on actual dataset. It only captures the first line

Comment: I ran it on your data structure, and it found all 3 city names...

Comment: This is the same answer as that given by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: My thoughts exactly.